# Conda Environment with specific Tensorflow and Numpy Version

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, conda, environment

I need to setup a conda environment for tensorflow. I do so via environment.yml file. I have to specify my version of tensorflow (latest 2.5.0) because otherwise conda installs tf 1.14. But because tensorflow seems not to work properly with the latest numpy version I want to use numpy 1.19 or older. With the following environment.yml conda cannot solve the environment, it says `Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.` but after that conda is not able to solve the problem.

```
name: gi-project
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - numpy=1.19
  - tensorflow=2.5.0
  - matplotlib
  - jupyterlab
  - pandas
  - joblib
  - scikit-learn
  - netcdf4
```

Why is this? I thought the reason for conda environments is to deal with different versions of packages?

Comment: Do you have a Windows operating system?

Comment: Yes, Windows 10

Answer (score 3):

`conda` looks at the packages that you want to install, check their dependencies and then determines which versions will work together. Package maintainers thereby impose limits. If we do

`conda search --info tensorflow`

we see that it has a dependency for `tensorflow-base=2.5.0`:

```
tensorflow 2.5.0 mkl_py38hbe2df88_0
-----------------------------------
file name   : tensorflow-2.5.0-mkl_py38hbe2df88_0.conda
name        : tensorflow
version     : 2.5.0
build       : mkl_py38hbe2df88_0
build number: 0
size        : 4 KB
license     : Apache 2.0
subdir      : win-64
url         : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/tensorflow-2.5.0-mkl_py38hbe2df88_0.conda
md5         : dc6f851db06000dc1e22965fc7f8946a
timestamp   : 2021-07-02 17:21:52 UTC
dependencies:
  - _tflow_select 2.3.0 mkl
  - python 3.8.*
  - tensorboard >=2.5.0
  - tensorflow-base 2.5.0 mkl_py38h9201259_0
  - tensorflow-estimator >=2.5.0
```

Going further down the line, doing `conda search --info tensorflow-base=2.5.0`:

```
tensorflow-base 2.5.0 mkl_py38h9201259_0
----------------------------------------
file name   : tensorflow-base-2.5.0-mkl_py38h9201259_0.conda
name        : tensorflow-base
version     : 2.5.0
build       : mkl_py38h9201259_0
build number: 0
size        : 63.3 MB
license     : Apache 2.0
subdir      : win-64
url         : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/tensorflow-base-2.5.0-mkl_py38h9201259_0.conda
md5         : fe8fa6dfa600d9158984e0676cf000db
timestamp   : 2021-06-25 13:11:22 UTC
dependencies:
  - abseil-cpp >=20210324.2,<20210324.3.0a0
  - absl-py >=0.10.0
  - astunparse >=1.6.3
  - flatbuffers
  - gast 0.4.0
  - giflib >=5.2.1,<5.3.0a0
  - google-pasta >=0.2
  - grpcio
  - h5py >=3.1.0
  - icu >=68.1,<69.0a0
  - jpeg >=9b,<10a
  - keras-preprocessing >=1.1.2
  - libcurl >=7.71.1,<8.0a0
  - libpng >=1.6.37,<1.7.0a0
  - libprotobuf >=3.14.0,<3.15.0a0
  - numpy >=1.20
  - openssl >=1.1.1k,<1.1.2a
  - opt_einsum 3.3.0.*
  - protobuf >=3.9.2
  - python >=3.8,<3.9.0a0
  - python-flatbuffers 1.12.*
  - scipy >=1.6.2
  - six >=1.15.0
  - snappy >=1.1.8,<2.0a0
  - sqlite >=3.36.0,<4.0a0
  - tensorboard >=2.5.0,<2.6
  - tensorflow-estimator >=2.5.0,<2.6
  - termcolor >=1.1.0
  - typing_extensions >=3.7.4
  - vc >=14.2,<15.0a0
  - vs2015_runtime >=14.27.29016,<15.0a0
  - wheel >=0.35,<0.36
  - wrapt >=1.11.2
  - zlib >=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0
```

As you can see, `numpy>=1.20` is a requirement. Therefore `conda` can only go ahead and determine that your requirements are not possible to go together, as whoever has created the `tensorflow-base=2.5.0` package has specified that it will not work with `numpy<1.20`

I suggest you try with `numpy=1.20` if you want to avoid the latest version (`1.21`)

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar problems with numpy and tensorflow not being compatible with each other.

I came across a [gist](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/47691) that suggested this incompatibility had been fixed in tensorflow 2.7 and later

For me, downloading tensorflow 2.10.0 required using the [condaforge](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/tensorflow) channel:

```
conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33008607)